# How to Create Accept/Decline Buttons with Boolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean, submit, checkmark

I have accept/decline as a switch:

```
<%= form_for @dueler do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :accept, class: 'someclass', :data => { 'on-text'=>'Decline', 'off-text'=>'Accept'} %> 
  <script>
    $("[class='someclass']").bootstrapSwitch();
  </script>
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit')  do %>
    Save
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm trying to make them into two separate buttons. If a user clicks one, how to make it where it would automatically submit with the appropriate `:accept` value:

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit')  do %>
  Accept # submits & makes :accept true
<% end %><br><br>

<%= button_tag(type: 'submit')  do %>
  Decline # submits & makes :accept false
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use f.button to pass a param that you'll use in the controller:

In your view:

```
<%= f.button "Accept", name: "button_action", value: "accept" %>
<%= f.button "Decline", name: "button_action", value: "decline" %>
```

In your controller use the param value:

```
if params['button_action'] == 'accept'
else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller... check the value of the submit-button - which will be either "accept" or "decline" and set the boolean based on that.

Answer (score 0):

**This is my experience**

When you make check box and did not set any value it autometically send boolean value. That means true or false. When Check box is checked value will be true or one and if box is unckecked then value will be false or 0.

Hope It helps.